# functions of id attribute if there is no hash character specified ? (beginner in HTML)

Tags: html, css, web, attributes

I am a beginner in HTML/CSS/Javascript and am trying to understand the code of a particular website.

To my understanding id attribute is given specific traits by using hash character and specifying a name for id in the  element. However, in this website, every line has its own id mentioned as you can see in the code example below, but in the beginning of the code, that is within the  element there is hash characters specified for any ids. and in the body element of the code, every line has a unique id specified. I was wondering if anyone knew why? I am also attaching the website below, in case anyone is interested in the functioning! I am trying to understand the different ways to use id attribute and its function and so was confused!

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Every element is an html.</title>
  <script src="scripts.js" defer></script>
  <style>
    .current { border: 1px solid red; }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
<p id="a">Every element is an a.</p>
  <p id="abbr">Every element is an abbr.</p>
  <p id="address">Every element is an address.</p>
  <!-- <p id="area">Every element is an area.</p> -->
  <p id="article">Every element is an article.</p>
  <p id="aside">Every element is an aside.</p>
  <!-- <p id="audio">Every element is an audio.</p> -->
  <p id="b">Every element is a b.</p>
  <!-- <p id="base">Every element is a base.</p> -->
  <p id="bdi">Every element is a bdi.</p>
  <p id="bdo">Every element is a bdo.</p>
  <p id="blockquote">Every element is a blockquote.</p>
  <p id="body">Every element is a body.</p>
```

link to website: https://whykatherine.github.io/every-element-is-an-html/)

Comment: You should add [minimal reproducible code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), so that people can understand your problem and help you. [see why you shouldn't post image as a code or an error](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question#:~:text=You%20should%20not%20post%20code,order%20to%20reproduce%20the%20problem.)

Comment: Could you describe in more detail what the problem/question is? The coder has given every element an id. I can't see why that is a problem. They don't seem to be using them in a stylesheet, but they are using them in the JavaScript. As long as ids are unique it's OK, if unusual, as far as HTML goes to give one to each element. However, this example is a rather special case and is coded as an example rather than a 'typical' website.